# Kafka trouble with multiple partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

If I use kafka topics with a single partition everything works fine.

If I use 5 kafka servers and a topic with 10 partitions, the partitions that are assigned to the controlling broker start with an offset of -1. Messages sent to those partitions are lost.

Combing through the logs I don't see any errors. Although I do see plenty of warnings that partitions are out of service  "INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=5, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-2 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION "

This was working fine until an os upgrade (dc/os) that enforces resource limits. I've increased resource allocation to comical proportions.

Below is the output of kafdrop for the first 5 partitions of the __consumer_offsets topic prior to any data being written.

Partition
First Offset
Last Offset 
Size
Leader
Replicas
In Sync Replicas
Preferred Leader?
Under Replicated?

```
0   0   0   0   3   3,1,2,4,5   1,2,3,4,5   Yes No

1   0   0   0   4   4,2,3,5,1   1,2,3,4,5   Yes No

2   0   0   0   5   5,3,4,1,2   1,2,3,4,5   Yes No

3   -1  -1  0   1   1,4,5,2,3   1,2,3,4,5   Yes No

4   0   0   0   2   2,5,1,3,4   1,2,3,4,5   Yes No
```

At this point kafka server 1 is running and it's log looks fine. Server 1 is also identified as the controlling broker.

Comment: If you describe the `__consumer_offsets` topic, what do you get?

Comment: Offsets cannot be -1 unless the leader of that partition is offline. Please check the logs of all brokers and processes of all servers

Comment: Partition First Offset Last Offset Size Leader Replicas In Sync Replicas Preferred Leader? Under Replicated?
0 0 0 0 3 3,1,2,4,5 1,2,3,4,5 Yes No
1 0 0 0 4 4,2,3,5,1 1,2,3,4,5 Yes No
2 0 0 0 5 5,3,4,1,2 1,2,3,4,5 Yes No
3 -1 -1 0 1 1,4,5,2,3 1,2,3,4,5 Yes No
4 0 0 0 2 2,5,1,3,4 1,2,3,4,5 Yes No 
Above is the first 5 lines from kafdrop before any data is written. This pattern repeats. The partitions assigned to the controlling broker have an offset of -1. After data is written all of the topics with the controlling broker as a replicant will become under-replicated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the formatted output of that command, but I'm not sure what else to tell you other than enable DEBUG logging on the brokers because at least one of them is failing

Comment: Yes. The servers are on lline. They are the one log that looks good as the others have the error mentioned above in them several times.

Comment: Ignore the `ReplicaFetcher` logs. Those are trying to read from a different server... There's some other broker that should be assigned the initial partition of that topic

Comment: fwif this is a dcos problem not a kafka problem. I don't know the full answer, but we have two side by side dcos systems. Both made the upgrade to 1.11 and both exhibited this problem. After a few weeks of running, one does and one does not. I hate to leave the "answer" their. If I can get a better answer, I will detail it here.

Comment: You might want to verify the `advertised.listener` is set correctly within Mesos so that the brokers know about each other on the correct network addresses